# Saving form object to model with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having trouble getting the form object to post, here is what I got so far just using test data I am getting setTarget.save is undefined.  I am able to get fetch/get calls to work successfully using a similar structure.

**The View**

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'text!templates/default/parent.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, parentTemplate) {
var defaultView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
      $(this.el).html(parentTemplate);
                this.render();
    },

            events: {
                'click #busNext': 'showTarget'
            },

            showTarget: function() {
      this.model.set({
        businessName: $('#busInfoName').val(),
      });
                this.model.save();
    },

            render: function() {
                this.setValidator();
      return this;
    }

});
return new defaultView;
});
```

**The Model**

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var setTarget = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('set target initialize');
    },

    url: 'test.htm',

    defaults: {
        businessName: "",
        businessPhone: ""
    }

    });

  return setTarget;
});
```

**The Collection**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
'models/setTarget'
], function($, _, Backbone, setTarget){
  var target = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: setTarget,

  });

  return new target;
});
```

**The Router**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
'validate',
'views/default/parent',
'models/setTarget',
'collections/target'
], function($, _, Backbone, validate, defaultView, setTarget, target) {
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
                    '': 'defaultAction',
                    'index': 'defaultAction',
    },

    defaultAction: function(actions) {
      this.changePage(defaultView, 'fade');
    },

    changePage: function(page, pageTransition) {
        $('body').append($(page.el));
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), { changeHash: true, transition: pageTransition     });
        }

    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: debug and inspect the 'setTarget' object in your view after the click. I would guess it's not a Backbone.Collection?

Comment: I have tried to offer an answer but in any step I was finding a new issue. In your example code there are many cases where you are using _Classes_ like _instances_. You have to create instances of your clases and play with the instances not with the Classes them self. Your RequireJS functions are returning Classes not instances and you are using these classes directly without instantiate them. Not only in `setTarget` also in `parentTemplate`...

Comment: thanks for the replies, I updated the code and included the router as well, I guess I am just confused how to set the model, any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, after reading them I decided to go about this a different way.  Instead of using the model.save, I used the collectioninstancename.fetch method and in the collection overrode the settings so that it would POST instead of GET and it seems to work fine.